# How to convert static pivot table to dynamic one in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project and I've to create a pivot table in MySQL.

```
SELECT date,
  MAX(IF(cropname = 'tomato', quantity, NULL)) AS Tomatoes,
  MAX(IF(Cropname = 'apple', quantity, NULL)) AS Apples,
  MAX(IF(cropname = 'banana', quantity, NULL)) AS Bananas,
  MAX(IF(Cropname = 'bengal gram', quantity, NULL)) AS Bengal_Gram,
  MAX(IF(Cropname = 'Spinach', quantity, NULL)) AS Spinach,
  MAX(IF(Cropname = 'Beet Root', quantity, NULL)) AS Beet_Root
From tempcrop
Group by date;
```

Currently I'm using this code to make a pivot table. How should I alter this code to make it a dynamic pivot table so that if I add new records to the main table the same gets reproduced here automatically.

I've already seen other questions on stackoverflow as well as other websites. It didn't work. I've tried this code

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(Cropname = ''',
      cropname,
      ''', quantity, NULL)) AS ',
      cropname
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tempcrop;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, ', @sql, ' FROM tempcrop GROUP BY date');
```

Comment: It didn't work. izzat so how did it no work?

Comment: Shows a warning at row 18. But I checked it. Its correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 5000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(cropname = ''',
      cropname,
      ''', quantity, NULL)) AS ''',
      cropname,''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  tempcrop;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, ', @sql, ' FROM tempcrop');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
```

This code works perfectly.